# Dynamic Event Binding using Widget's Selector String

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I retrieve the selector string inside a jQuery UI custom object, for the purpose of binding events to dynamically created elements?

**Example**:

```
$.widget( "custom.myCustomWidget", {

    // the constructor
    _create: function() 
    {
        $('body').on(
            'click',
            this.element.selector, // How can I retrieve this?
            function(){ /* Do somthing */ }
        );
    }
});
```